# Instance of 'VersionSkew' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run my app which was work perfectly and then when I close it and trying to run it again this error appeared

> starting build daemon...
>   10.5s Instance of 'VersionSkew' 
>   Exited (1)

I have no idea about it, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? It worked for me.

Comment: I tried but the same message appears .. I think i have to change my flutter version to stable